# How to zip/compress the Multipart HTTP request sent by the client

Tags: http, compression, gzip, multipart, multipartentity

I am using apache httpclient 4.2 to send Multipart HTTP PUT request. The client has to upload large size binary data of the order of 500 MB. Hence compression is required.
I wish to compress the whole Multipart HTTP request and inform the server through header Content-Encoding: gzip. I control the server as well as client code.

Note: I am aware of the approach where I can selectively compress the large size binary data & not the whole request but for now I am ruling out that approach.

The httpclient's HttpRequestInterceptor class doesn't provide a handle to the request input stream or an entity to compress the request.

I have searched on the web & found few related links(below) but none of them works
 1. http://old.nabble.com/compressing-multipart-request-from-custom-client-tt27804438.html#a27811350
 2. http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#protocol_interceptors - This link says that "Protocol interceptors can also manipulate content entities enclosed with messages - transparent content compression / decompression being a good example." but don't know how to get the desired functionality.

Please give me some direction, if possible some sample code.

Answer (score 2):

I was finally able to solve this requirement by

1. creating a org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity object reqEntity.
2. Adding the compressed binary part to the HTTP request

   ByteArrayBody binaryData =
                     new ByteArrayBody(compressedData, "binary/octet-stream", "N/A");
      binaryParts.add(binaryData);
      reqEntity.addPart("uniqueId", binaryPart);